# BigQuery : transform row into columns dynamically

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dynamic-pivot

In **BigQuery**

Table issue_fields :

| issue_id | field_name | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | city | NY |
| 101 | size | 10 m2 |
| 103 | postalcode | 1020 |
| 103 | city | SF |

Table issues :

```
| issue_id | created_date
```

I want, in BigQuery, to create a table which is the issues table with n new columns, every column is a field_name, for all field_name in the table issue_fields.

Desired output :

| issue_id | created_date | city | size | postalcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023 | NY | 10 m2 |  |
| 103 | 2022 | SF |  | 1020 |

Tried with ChatGPT without success

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation :

```
select issue_id,
       max(created_date) as created_date,
       max(case when field_name = 'city' then field_value end ) as city,
       max(case when field_name = 'size' then field_value end ) as size,
       max(case when field_name = 'postalcode' then field_value end ) as postalcode
from mytable
group by issue_id
```

Comment: How to do it dynamically without specifying every fields manually ?

Answer (score 0):

you need a script to accomplish this

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE dynamic_fields STRING ;
    -- This execute block selects all field_name
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
      WITH
        fields AS (
          SELECT 101 AS issue_id, "city" AS field_name, "NY" as field_value
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 101 AS issue_id, "size" AS field_name, "10m2" as field_value
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 103 AS issue_id, "postalcode" AS field_name, "1020" as field_value
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 103 AS issue_id, "county" AS field_name, "SF" as field_value
      ) SELECT 

---- The string_agg the list of all possible values you want to select ----

string_agg( DISTINCT CONCAT("'",fields.field_name,"'") )
      FROM fields
    """) INTO dynamic_fields;
    SELECT dynamic_fields;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
         WITH
         fields_set AS (
           SELECT 101 AS issue_id, "city" AS field_name, "NY" as field_value
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 101 AS issue_id, "size" AS field_name, "10m2" as field_value
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 103 AS issue_id, "postalcode" AS field_name, "1020" as field_value
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 103 AS issue_id, "county" AS field_name, "SF" as field_value
       ) SELECT *
       FROM fields_set

-- This pivot section selects into the distinct list in previous block

       PIVOT(COUNT(fields_set.issue_id) FOR fields_set.field_name IN (%s))""",dynamic_fields);
    END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the following output (excluding the `created_date` field) using the below code.

```
SELECT
  issue_id,
  MAX(IF(field_name = 'city', field_value, NULL)) AS city,
  MAX(IF(field_name = 'size', field_value, NULL)) AS size,
  MAX(IF(field_name = 'postalcode', field_value, NULL)) AS postalcode
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  issue_id
```

This will use if statements to extract the key value pairs, returning the desired output table.

Comment: Thanks ! How to do it dynamically without specifying every fields manually ?